# Export libraries which are used in compile & running MSVC++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, compilation, shared-libraries

I am developing a C++ program which is using 6 different libraries (like Boost, OpenCV, Protobuf etc). I've compiled and installed all required libraries on my development PC. I want to export the program to work in another computer standalone. I can copy all the shared libraries to a folder and put the executable next to it but it will be really useful as my program's size would be enormous. Is it possible that MSVC++ exports all the shared libraries (and maybe the include files too) which are used in compilation?

Edit: Let me make clear the question.

- I've libraries & header files all around in my PC (Like C:\boost\lib, D:\Workspace\opencv\lib etc..)
- I don't use most of the libraries in these folders in my application.
- I want to run my application at another computer.
- I don't want to install all the libraries to the new computer.
- I want only that MSVC export the required(used) shared libraries to another folder that I specify so I can copy only 1 folder containing only required libraries in it.
- Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Exports from where to where else? Are you asking why Microsoft doesn't ship a large assortment of third-party libraries with every Windows installation just in case some application needs some of them?

Comment: If these are shared libs, then you only need the coresponding DLLs at runtime. If they are static libs, you don't need anything (except whatever you link dynamically - like CRT etc.).

Comment: They are shared, as I've mentioned.